# Cycle through empty columns in python

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I'm on Jupyter Notebook and Python.

My current database is:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dicionario = {'nome_adm': ['CC Brasil', 
                   'ABC Futuro',
                   'Tabuao'], 
              
              'nome': ['brasil fundo de investimento em cotas ', 
                   np.nan,
                   np.nan], 
                   
          'publico': [' publico em geral ', 
                   'investidores profissionais',
                   np.nan], 
                  
          'texto': [np.nan,
                    'publico bom',
                    np.nan,
                   ]}
                   
data = pd.DataFrame(dicionario)
data
```

The result of the above script is:

[image: dataframe image]

I need to write in the texto column the term "great audience", if in the column nome and publico, both main nulls, how do I solve this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.loc()` together with `.isna()` on the column `texto` to achieve it:

```
data['texto'].loc[data['nome'].isna() & data['publico'].isna()] = "great audience"
```

Result:

```
print(data)


     nome_adm                                    nome                     publico           texto
0   CC Brasil  brasil fundo de investimento em cotas            publico em geral              NaN
1  ABC Futuro                                     NaN  investidores profissionais     publico bom
2      Tabuao                                     NaN                         NaN  great audience
```

Answer (score 0):

First use `.isna().all(axis=1)` to determine the row where `nome`, `publico` and `texto` columns are all `NaN`.

Then use [pandas.DataFrame.mask()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) to replace the `texto` column value where condition is True.

```py
m = data[['nome', 'publico', 'texto']].isna().all(axis=1)

data['texto'] = data['texto'].mask(m, 'great audience')
```

```
print(data)

     nome_adm                                    nome                     publico           texto
0   CC Brasil  brasil fundo de investimento em cotas            publico em geral              NaN
1  ABC Futuro                                     NaN  investidores profissionais     publico bom
2      Tabuao                                     NaN                         NaN  great audience
```